# Validação de dados de entrada com uso de funções , try e except

Tags: python, exceção

```
try:
    number = int(input("Por favor, digite o seu número aqui e veja o que acontece: "))
except (ValueError, TypeError):
    print ("Por favor, insira somente números inteiros positivos")

try:
    collatz(number)
except (NameError):  
    print ("Não é possível executar a operação sem uma entrada válida.")
```

Preciso incluir nesse código validação usando try e excep, se caso o usuário digitar string (a,b,c...) ou caractere especial, ele mostre erro e solicite novamente o inteiro.

Comment: A minha pergunta é específica, não tem duplicidade. Com a minha pergunta, obtive a resposta que não obtive antes de faze-la.

Answer (score 2):

```
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input("Por favor, digite o seu número aqui e veja o que acontece: "))
    except:
        print ("Por favor, insira somente números inteiros positivos")
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

**Código:**

```
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input("Por favor, digite o seu número aqui e veja o que acontece: "))
    except:
        print ("Por favor, insira somente números inteiros positivos")
```

OBS: se for apenas com números inteiros é `int`, se for com números com ponto flutuante (decimais) é `float`.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!